# What Interest Rate used to calculate opportunity cost?

Tags: interest-rate, nonexpert, opportunity-cost

What Interest Rate used to calculate opportunity cost (Calculating Future Value/Present Value)?

Usually in the textbook it said that the rate used is government bonds interest rate(since it's risk free), but government bonds interest rates varies depends on the loan term. Which one do we choose? also since the opportunity cost basically calculate the return for risk-free assets, shouldn't we use bonds yield instead?